# MooTools Classes and Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, mootools, knockout.js

I was trying to keep my code a bit cleaner by using the OOP patterns that MooTools provides in combination with Knockout.js

I can't seem to get it to work as Knockout returns some function (the property function, meh?) when it data binds the values. If the values are retrieved with javascript however, it works as exprected. I made a quick jsFiddle so you can test it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/tixz/JK2jt/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current structure, the observables are created on the prototype of your class.  Knockout does not intend on them being on the prototype (they can't be shared as they keep private state), and an internal function `ko.isObservable` fails, because of it.   This causes the unwrapping code in KO does not realize that it needs to retrieve the underlying value for your observables.

You would have to write it like:

```
var ViewModel = new Class({
    initialize: function(secondVal){
        this.someProp = ko.observable('Here is my value');
        this.anotherProp = ko.observable(secondVal);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/JK2jt/9/

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you can't use `ko.observable` in your class definition ... those properties have to be initialized uniquely for each instance.